# pass checkbox values to bootstrap modals and calling div modals based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get the checkbox values into the div modals based on the corresponding button clicks. I'm unable to achieve it.

Desired result: The corresponding buttons should pass the checkbox values in the corresponding modal div and display them.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var favorite = [];
     $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
      favorite.push($(this).val());
    });

$("button1").click(function() { 
 $("#myModal").modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $("#checkid").html("I play these games " +"<br>" + favorite.join("<br>"));
    }); 
 });
$("button2").click(function() {
  $("#myModal2").modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $("#checkid").html("I dont Play these games " +"<br>" + favorite.join("<br>"));
    }); 
 }); 

});
```

```html
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         This are the Games that I usually play, and i'm really go at it:<br>
        <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This are the Games that I don't usually play, but would love to:<br>
        <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form>
  <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
  <br>
  <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</form>
<button  id = "button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >I play these games</button>
  <button  id = "button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">I dont play these games</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have missed some `#` character in many place. try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid");
        $(p).html("I play these games ");
        $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
            $(p).html($(p).html() + '<br>' + $(this).val());
        });      
    }); 
    $("#button2").click(function() {
        var p=$("#myModal2 #checkid");
        $(p).html("I don't play these games ");
        $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
            $(p).html($(p).html() + '<br>' + $(this).val());
        }); 
    });
});
```

In HTML, change

```
<button  id = "button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >I play these games</button>
```

to

```
<button  id = "button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >I play these games</button>
```

Comment: @jonu. the code works perfectly. Im trying to display the checked values in a textarea in the modal with some predefined text appended. here is one on the button click even im trying to edit.

Comment: What happens is that for every checkbox value selected, the extra text get added, which is not correct. It needs to be appended at the end in the textarea. Can this be done? `$("#button1").click(function()                { var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid");  $(p).html("I don't play these games");                                                     $.each($("input[name='TS']:checked"), function() { $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()+ '\n' + "--------------------------" + '\n' + "Thank you for contacting us SAVED!" + '\n' + "-----------------------------------"); });`

Comment: I am still not getting what exactly is your requirement

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for:      $("#button1").click(function() {
        var p=$("#myModal1 #checkid");
        $(p).html("I don't play these games"); 
        $.each($("input[name='TS']:checked"), function() { 
            $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()); 
        });
        $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n --------------------------\n Thank you for contacting us SAVED! \n -----------------------------------');
    });

Comment: I wish to display the checkbox values along with some appended text  Desired output:                                                                                       `(Checkbox values)                                                                                   -------------------------------                                                                               Thank you contacting us                                                                                        -------------------------------- `

Comment: Have you tried the code above? append your pre-defined text after .each() method(not inside it) to the <p> or <textarea> like : $('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + 'Your pre-defined text')

Comment: The code worked. everything according to my requirements. thanks

Comment: it was exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must rewrite your selector: `$('#button1')` instead of `$('button1')` and move the snippet

```
var favorite = [];
$.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
  favorite.push($(this).val());
});
```

and place it inside your click function, otherwise your favorite array will load only once, when the page finish loads.